# Selendroid Inspector device Screen not appear

Tags: testing, automated-tests, selendroid

When i connect my hybrid app using selendroid server, Inspector tool not displaying device's screen(Broken Image/Empty image appear). And also nothing is appear on Java/HTML source tabs. [example Screen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSbji.png)

I use followings Command to Start the Selendroid Server

java -jar *Jar_file* -app *app_file*

and also i have tried

java -jar *Jar_file* -deviceScreenshot -app *app_file*

Code i used in Java eclipse

```
SelendroidCapabilities capa = new SelendroidCapabilities();
capa.setAut(My_application_id);
driver = new SelendroidDriver(capa);
```

What should i do to get a device screen in Inspector tool ?